# an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has child records

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i have 2 table, in table "nilai" :

```
alter table nilai
add( 
constraint nil_kd_makul_fk foreign key(kd_makul) references makul(kd_makul));
```

i'm disabled for data entry/update column

```
alter table nilai disable constraint nil_nim_fk
```

after update value :

```
update nilai
set nim = '96123'
where kd_makul = 'A1'
```

after i'm enable constraint :

```
alter table nilai enable constraint nil_nim_fk
```

when i execute :

```
SQL Error: ORA-02298: cannot validate (FAUZI.NIL_NIM_FK) - parent keys not found
02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
           child records.
*Action:   Obvious
```

i need help

Comment: This means that there is no row with `nim` value '96123' in the parent table, whatever table that may be.  Note: (1) the constraint you show in your first code example is not the constraint that is failing (different name), and (2) the "cause" shown after the error is misleading.  "Parent keys not found" is the issue.

Comment: The constraint which is being violated is `NIL_NIM_FK`. What does this constraint validate? It's not shown in your question. Please edit your question and include the definition of `NIL_NIM_FK`. Thanks.